# Laravel - php artisan route:list displaying weird characters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using phpStorm 2018, and frequently when I typed `php artisan route:list` my route list appeared corrupted like:

This is a printscreen of the routes:

[image]

Comment: Can you Please the restart your system and then check?

Answer (score 0):

use cmd prompt, I use cmd prompt in Linux and maximize its size. it display smoothly

Comment: I see, yes, it displayed correctly in cmd prompt, but I do not understand why in the phpStorm terminal, it shows these weird looking characters,do you experienced this as well?

Comment: @yeln, does your phpstorm require an update? I use PHPStorm and never have this issue?